# limited access to a login user that should not be see more then 5 user profile fuelphp framwork

Tags: php, fuelphp

I want to give limited access to a login user that shouldn't be see more then 5 user profiles on that site. If user login in [franchiseindia](http://franchiseindia.co.in) data in php.

Comment: What have you tried so far?? Can you add your code?

Comment: i want way for perform that process

Comment: You have to try out with some way and ask doubt on that, not implementation.

Comment: i have login user id and a business id i want to count login user to count if >5 buseness-id click (mean see on click) then data not show

Answer (score 0):

1. Create column history in user table (you will save json_encoded profile_ids and date when he viewed it)
2. Every time user goes to profile check count of profile_ids in history column by current day.

   - If less than 5 you update the column with updated json_encoded array, which will include only unique profile_ids visited today.
   - Else - abort (error him in face)